# Display Current date with additional 30 days of calculation - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display current date by finding string and replacing with current date, its working fine, but additionally I want to display another date where if string has some comma seprated value then it will add to the current date and will display accodrdingly, So lets say if I add (,30) in string it will add 30 days additional in current date and display

```js
var setCurrentDate = function() {
        var disclaimerStr = $(".dynamic-date").html(),
            currDateStr = "{currentdate}",
            date = new Date(),
            months = [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ],
            currDate =
                months[date.getMonth()] +
                " " +
                date.getDate() +
                ", " +
                date.getFullYear(),
            newDisclaimerStr;

        if (disclaimerStr.indexOf(currDateStr) != -1) {
            newDisclaimerStr = disclaimerStr.replace(currDateStr, currDate);
            $(".dynamic-date").html(newDisclaimerStr);
        }
    };
    setCurrentDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic-date">
  <b>Current Date</b> : {currentdate} <br><br>
  <b>Extended Date</b> : {currentdate,30} <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't provide ANY information, why is it runnable? Oh, I see, you haven't even tried to implement `,30` and want someone to write it for you ... hint: use regexp to search for something like `/\{currentdate(,\d+)\}/`

Comment: yes its working in first case but in 2nd case its not working because the logic is not there for secnd case

Comment: not so clear on the hint, could you please refer some example?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```js
var setCurrentDate = function() {
        var disclaimerStr = $(".dynamic-date").html(),
            currDateStr = "{currentdate}",
            date = new Date(),
            months = [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ],
            currDate =
                months[date.getMonth()] +
                " " +
                date.getDate() +
                ", " +
                date.getFullYear(),
            newDisclaimerStr;

        if (disclaimerStr.indexOf(currDateStr) != -1) {
            newDisclaimerStr = disclaimerStr.replace(currDateStr, currDate);
            $(".dynamic-date").html(newDisclaimerStr);
        }
        
        
        var reg = new RegExp(/\{currentdate(,(\d+))\}/);
        var currDateStr2 = '{currentdate,30}'; // you need to change here!
        var days = parseInt(reg.exec(currDateStr2)[2], 10);
        console.log(days) //30
        
        var date2 = new Date();
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + days);
        
        console.log(date2) // "2019-04-27T09:13:00.789Z"
        
        
        
    };
    setCurrentDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic-date">
  <b>Current Date</b> : {currentdate} <br><br>
  <b>Extended Date</b> : {currentdate,30} <br><br>
</div>
```